# display connected clients on a java chat messenger n a jtextarea of swing based application

Tags: java, swing, sockets

how to display connected clients on a java chat messenger that involve socket program on a jtextarea of swing based application
[server swing gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li6lV.png)

i want whenever any client connect/disconnect the info is displayed on jtextarea of above server frame.
As my project include a chat room so whenever a client enter a chat room there also i want to display list of all connected/disconnected clients to whom any user can do private chat.
[client chatroom gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z4iP.png)

```
//this is event handling code when events start from serverJFrame gui       
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"start", "Hello",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


       BroadcastServer.broadcastmain();



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                
 private void jPasswordField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     try
      {
      Textvalue = new String(jPasswordField2.getPassword());
      if(Textvalue.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
             {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"EMPTY PASSWORD FIELD","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             return;
             }
       new DBconnect();//DBconnect is a class that connect with database and validate password
       if(DBconnect.check==101)
       {
       jButton4.setEnabled(true);
       jButton3.setEnabled(true);
       jButton2.setEnabled(true);
       }
      }

      catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
} 
//broadcastmain() is in BroadcastServer class
public static void broadcastmain()
{
try
{
System.out.println("server started");
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1500);
while(true)
{
System.out.println("waiting for client request"); 
Socket sk=ss.accept();
al.add(sk);
new ClientThread(al,sk);
} 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}    

//ClientThread class
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
ArrayList al;
Socket sk;
public static ArrayList<String> ar1=new ArrayList<String>();
    ClientThread(ArrayList al,Socket sk)
        {
            this.al=al;
            this.sk=sk;
            start();
        }
    public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
                String name=din.readUTF();
                System.out.println(name+" : connected");

                ar1.add(name);

                DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
                String msg="welcome "+name+" ,start chatting";
                dout.writeUTF(msg);
                dout.flush();
                    while(true)
                    {
                    String msg1=din.readUTF();
                    if(msg1.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                        {
                            al.remove(sk);
                            ar1.remove(name);
                            System.out.println(name+" disconnected");
                            break;

                        }
                    broadcastMsg(name+" : "+msg1);
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
//ChatClient class for client
public class ChatClient {
static FileWriter fr;
public  static String name;
public static void ChatClientmain()
{
            try
            {

                System.out.println("client started");
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Enter your name");

                name=br.readLine();
                 fr=new FileWriter(name,true);
                Socket sk=new Socket("localhost",1500);
                System.out.println("client connected");
                DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
                dout.writeUTF(name);
                dout.flush();
                new ReaderThread(sk);
                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter message, Enter stop to terminate");
                    String msg=br.readLine();
                    dout.writeUTF(msg);
                    fr.write(msg);
                    dout.flush();
                    fr.flush();
                    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("YOUR DISCONNECTED");
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
             catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
//ReaderThread class
public class ReaderThread extends Thread{
Socket sk;
ReaderThread(Socket sk)
{
this.sk=sk;
setDaemon(true);
start();
}
public void run()
{
try
{
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
    while(true)
    {
        String msg=din.readUTF();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
             catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please post the relevant snippets of code.

Comment: See also [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: Gentlemen sorry for inconvenience, i think now snippets of code are posted. so its kinda clear i guess.